# Current nth-of-type select same nth-of-type dropdown

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a list of buttons as follows:

```
<button id="serviceModal1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal1" tabindex="-1">Hind 150€</button>
<button id="serviceModal2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal2" tabindex="-1">Hind 250€</button>
```

Etc..

And a contact form in a modal which has a dropdown.

```
<select name="menu-89" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select dropdown-menu" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi">TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi</option>
<option value="TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi">TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi</option>
</select>
```

So clicking button:nth-of-type(1) should pre-select option:nth-of-type(1) and so on.

```
$('#serviceModal1').click(function () {
    $('select option:eq(1)').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

How would I achieve this dynamically?

The modals are also dynamically created with ACF and using Contact form 7. Could this be related to some of the codes below not working?

```
<?php if( have_rows('modal','option') ):
    $counter3 = 1;
    while ( have_rows('modal','option') ) : the_row(); ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="serviceModal<?php echo $counter3; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog wide-grid">
        <div class="modal-controls">
            <div class="btn-next">
                <span class="ion-chevron-right"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-prev">
                <span class="ion-chevron-left"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span class="ion-close"></span></button>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body content-inner">
         <div class="flexing">
            <div  class="flex">
                <?php the_sub_field('modal-1','option'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="flex">
                <?php the_sub_field('modal-2','option'); ?>
                <?php the_sub_field('form','option') ;?>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php $counter3++; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Since this is also not having effect for testing purpose:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('select.dropdown-menu option:eq(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Comment: Need to create the selector dynamically on click itself.

Comment: @VinodkumarG `create the selector ` ?? how ?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you can get the `index()` from the clicked button, then use it to select the associated `option` using `eq()`, before using `prop()` to select the option. Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('select option').eq($(this).index('button')).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal1" tabindex="-1">Hind 150€</button>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal2" tabindex="-1">Hind 250€</button>

<select name="menu-89" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select dropdown-menu" aria-invalid="false">
  <option value="TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi">TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi 150€</option>
  <option value="TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi">TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi 250€</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('button[id^=serviceModal]').click(function(){
  var id= $(this).attr('id').substr(12)-1;
  $('select option:eq('+id+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Comment: `option:eq(id)` won't work as you expect. You need to concatenate the value. Also note that the options are index 0 and 1, not 1 and 2. Using `substr()` to dissect the `id` string is also *very* brittle.

Comment: Ahh you are almost there if you do not hard code `substr(12` because this fail case of  `data-target="#serviceModal12"`

Comment: This seems close but no effect unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

This should do. Id and getting it's number in the end should be the option that getting selected.

```js
$("button[id^='serviceModal']").click(function () {
var num = /\d+(?=\D*$)/.exec($(this).attr('id'));
 $('select option:eq('+(num-1)+')').prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="serviceModal1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal1" tabindex="-1">Hind 150€</button>
<button id="serviceModal2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal2" tabindex="-1">Hind 250€</button>


<select name="menu-89" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select dropdown-menu" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi">TOP 150 ettevõtet autopargi järgi</option>
<option value="TOP 300 ettevõtet autopargi järgi">TOP 250 ettevõtet autopargi järgi</option>
</select>
```